# Image in a Tumblr theme does not display in Firefox

Tags: html, css, tumblr

My friend asked me to add a header image advert to his Tumblr blog, http://proudlockstyle.com. 
(I did not make the theme)

I went into the theme editor and added the necessary html just inside the main container:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <a href="http://www.reiss.com/">
        <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/1gdukju/Qrtmei9p1/all_banners_mens1_468x60.jpg" />
    </a>    
</div>
```

This worked fine in Chrome, Safari and even IE! But the image does not show when the site is viewed in Firefox. When I inspect it in Firebug the `<img>` tag is grayed out.

Can anyone identify why the image isn't showing?

Comment: Maybe it has something to with the name of the file `all_banners_mens1_468x60.jpg.jpg`? Try uploading the file again without having the double `.jpg`.

Comment: updated, it seems the image had a superflous .jpg on the end - doesn't seem to have solved the issue though.

Comment: It seems odd. If you add an `alt` tag to the image, the `alt` tag shows, but Firefox won't load the image onto the page.

Comment: Yes I am usually OK at resolving these kind of things but this one has me a bit stumped. Although I am quite unfamiliar with Tumblr themes

Comment: Why my firefox shows your picture perfectly?!

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the url e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/3TsD9/ Where are you uploading the image? As you can see in the fiddle and image straight out of a post seems to work fine.

Comment: I can see the banner, using Firefox. Maybe you use AdBlock (or similar) and this image (resp. the URL resp. a keyword of the URL) is blocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running adblock in your Firefox right? Change the name drop the banners bit. It doesn't show in my Chrome either unless I disable adblock

Comment: Ahh, that must be the reason. Yes I have adblock on FF but not on chrome. Have changed the image filename to not have "banner" in it. Unfortuantely I am at work where I only have chrome and IE but if anyone can confirm it now shows that would be good. I will conclude it is adblock however.

Comment: It does indeed show now with Adblock enabled Harry. Thanks tw ;)